# How do I get a property of an object by string?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, in an array. Doing this:

```
alert(myObject.cats[1].nickname);
```

will output 'fluffykins' or whatever the nickname is.

Is there a way to access this property by string? ie.

```
var param = 'nickname';
alert(myObject.cats[1].{param});
```

Comment: This is JavaScript - nothing specific to jQuery here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use square brackets as usual.

```
myObject.cats[1][param]
```

Comment: +1 This article on quirksmode outlines associative arrays very well, good reading http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var test = { 'prop1': 'test' };

alert(test['prop1']);
```

Comment: Ah fair play, habit from emailing :)