# use string to search json

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var id = 1;
console.log(myJSON.users[id].name);
```

This outputs "Tom"

I want to output the same with:

```
var id = 1;
var attr = "name"
console.log(myJSON.users[id].attr);
```

Now, jQuery is searching for "attr" instead of the string inside attr. How can I do this?

Comment: See what you already did with `[id]` there? Well give that a shot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a property of an object by string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301908/how-do-i-get-a-property-of-an-object-by-string)

Comment: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: Just deleted the "." and it works. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: FYI, jQuery isn't searching for anything. This is all JavaScript syntax. jQuery !== JavaScript. jQuery is just another code library, and JavaScript is the programming language it's written in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you if you break it down further so you can better see what's going on:

```
var id = 1;
var user = myJSON.users[id];
```

That gets you the user. You can then do the same to get the name:

```
var attr = "name"
console.log(user[attr]);
```

Putting it all together you can do:

```
var id = 1;
var attr = "name";
console.log(myJSON.users[id][attr]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using variables to define what information to retrieve, use square brackets, like:

```
var id = 1;
var attr = "name"
console.log(myJSON.users[id][attr]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
var json = {
    users: {
        0: {name:"A"},
        1: {name:"B"}
    }
};

var attr = "name";
console.log(json.users[0][attr]); //"A"
```

?